# Overwrite image buffer (inside Adafruit SSD1306)

Tags: array, pointer, buffer

I'd like to add a method that replaces the entire image buffer into the [Adafruit_SSD1306](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/master/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp) library. I haven't worked with dynamic memory handling for ages and I'm not sure how to just simply overwrite its pointer to point to a different memory address where my newBuffer is.

```
static uint8_t buffer[SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT * SSD1306_LCDWIDTH / 8] = {}

void Adafruit_SSD1306::setBuffer(uint8_t * newBuffer) {
  buffer = newBuffer; // not sure which operator to use
}
```

Update: Passing by reference wouldn't work. The question is: how to overwrite by copying? Would it work well with `memcpy`?

```
void Adafruit_SSD1306::setBuffer(uint8_t * newBuffer) {
  memcpy(newBuffer, buffer, (SSD1306_LCDWIDTH * SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT / 8));
}
```

Update: The code above doesn't seem to making anything. This one neither:

```
void Adafruit_SSD1306::setBuffer(uint8_t * newBuffer) {
  for(int16_t i = 0; i < SSD1306_LCDWIDTH * SSD1306_LCDHEIGHT / 8; i++) {
    buffer[i] = 255; // experimenting
  }
}
```

Update: `setPixel` doesn't work either. - Needed `display.display();` :)

Comment: Do you want to copy the contents of `newBuffer` in `buffer` or rewrite `buffer` to be `uint8_t*` which you can change?

Comment: (I'm feeding the `newBuffer` from network and) I wan't a solution that replaces the image `buffer` the fastest. I don't mind making some changes in the library as long as it's easy. :)

Comment: Does copying have big overhead compared to passing the value by reference?

Comment: I've just realised that passing by reference might not work as the buffer is in a specific location in the memory, can't be elsewhere.

Comment: Even when done properly, changing the code to point to a new buffer location won't free the old buffer.  Arduinos tend to have limited RAM, so you probably want to *copy* the contents into the existing static allocation, not abandon a big chunk of memory.

Comment: How would copying look like?

Comment: Something like `memcpy()` or similar most likely.

Comment: Can you check the update please?

Comment: `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`. You exchanged the argument order in your `memcpy` call.. Destination must be `buffer`. You must of course also guarantee that `newBuffer` has the required length.